# Limitting user's ability with "premium" and set time intervals

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to monetize my website using "premium" plans. I am trying to make it such that eg normally, you will be required to wait 1hour before you can create your second blogpost for that specific user, and if you try to post during that one hour, you will receive a message saying that you have to wait for {{ remaining time }} left.

I'm totally new to monetization. Could someone share how I can impose the 1hour waiting time before a post can be created and also how to create a "premium plan" where the code can "recognise" this "premium" plan and hence auto shorten the duration..like the payment etc.

I also plan to monetise other functionalities so if any kind soul can give an example of this, it would really help as I try to adapt the same method taught to other functionalities...Thank you!

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
 title                  = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
 author                 = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 slug                   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
 date_published         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="date published")
 date_updated           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="date updated")

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateBlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['chief_title']
```

views.py

```
def create_blog_view(request):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateBlogPostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)    
        if form.is_valid():
            obj.save()
            return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
        else:
            context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/create_blog.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to calling `obj.save()` in your views.py, run a query to see if this author has a previous post with a published date greater than 1 hour ago. If they do, decide what you want to do: send to another page, save to a draft model, or save in draft mode, then push out to a 'pay for premium' option. I think you'd want to push to the premium option before they type up the blog.

EDIT: code add after form is valid (do the import at top of script). Untested and written in S/O editor window by memory, so may be something not quite right.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def create_blog_view(request):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateBlogPostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)    
        if form.is_valid():
            threshold_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
            posted_within_threshold = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=obj.author, date_published__gt=threshold_time).exists()
            
            if posted_within_threshold:
                # do what you want like save as draft [you'd need a draft property for this example]
                obj = form.save(commit=False)
                obj.draft = True
                obj.save()
                # redirect to page with notice about premium
                return redirect('HomeFeed:go_premium')
            else:
               form.save()
               return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
        else:
            context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/create_blog.html", context)
```

EDIT 2: (probably a better way to pass the time remaining to your context, but I'm trying to do this without pasting into an actual editor and trying it out. I'm not even sure this gives you time remaining, but play around with it until you get what you need).

```
def create_blog_view(request):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateBlogPostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)    
        if form.is_valid():
            threshold_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
            most_recent = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=obj.author).order_by('-date_published)[:1]
            if most_recent:
                # careful here with timezones 
                if most_recent.first().date_published > threshold_time:
                    context.update({'show_premium_msg':True,
                                    'wait_time': datetime.now() - most_recent.first().date_published,})
            else:
               form.save()
               return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
        else:
            context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/create_blog.html", context)
```

Comment: Hey man! Would you mind showing how the code should look like :) quite unsure of how to write time data in code

Comment: Yo btw it should be does not exist instead of exists() right? Because Eid it exists means I have made a post within the past hour so I shouldn’t be allowed to post

Comment: You can accomplish it that way; I'd go with if a post exists with a published date greater than one hour ago, then they get sent to premium prompt. Or you could go with if a post doesn't exist in the last hour, then save this one they just did. Depends what you want to happen in your 'if' vs your 'else'.

Comment: if you don't want to save the current blog post, but instead throw it away and post a message with the time, you could get the maximum post by this author. If the time on that post is greater than one hour ago, find the difference, put it in your context and don't redirect, but check for that message in your 'create_blog.html' template - showing it if necessary. That way the post they just typed will still be on screen.

Comment: and those`obj.` should be `form.` will update.

Comment: appreciate the help bro, could you give me until this Sunday to get back to you on the code :) will work on it on Sunday! @AMG meanwhile I upvoted you :)